# Tower and log* in Haskell giving me headaches

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to implement the [Power Tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) in Haskell. The `tower` function is defined as:

[image]

and it's inverse function `log'` looks like:

[image]

The `tower` function was easy enough to implement:

```
tower :: (Num a, Integral b, Eq a) => b -> a -> b
tower n 0 = 1
tower n k = n^(tower n (k - 1))
```

However it's the `log'` function that's giving me troubles:

```
log' b 0 = 0
log' b k = 1 + log' $ floor $ logBase b k
```

Please ignore the fact that `tower` is unsafe since it won't necessarily terminate.

My real problem is that I can't seem to find a decent way to call `log'`. In it's current
form, `ghci` tells me it's type is:

```
log' :: (RealFrac s, Integral s, Floating s, Fractional a) => s -> s -> a
```

This is because of the type signatures of `log` and `floor`.

So even though this type-checks, I think it is impossible to invoke because there
is no `s` so that `s` is both a member of `RealFrac` and of `Integral`.

I first thought of adding `Int` as an instance to the `RealFrac` class
but I soon realised this is impossible because this requires `Int` to be `Fractional` and
I can't seem to find a valid implementation of `Fractional`s `(/) :: a -> a -> a` operator for 
`Int`s.

How does one fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you need to convert back from the integral type you get from `floor` into the floating type that `log'` can take.

Your code didn't actually type-check as it stood because you missed out the `b` in the recursive call to `log'`, but this works for me:

```
log' b 0 = 0
log' b k = 1 + log' b (fromIntegral $ floor $ logBase b k)
```

This produces this type:

```
log' :: (Floating a1, Num a, RealFrac a1) => a1 -> a1 -> a
```

If you want `log'` to take an `Integral` type instead, put the `fromIntegral` at the use of `k` instead:

```
log' b 0 = 0
log' b k = 1 + log' b (floor $ logBase b $ fromIntegral k)
```

This gives this type:

```
log' :: (Floating a1, Integral a2, Num a, RealFrac a1) => a1 -> a2 -> a
```

Given the special case for `k=0` this may be the more safer/more natural way to write it.

Comment: duh! So simple! I must be really tired today. Strange that it didn't compile for you. What haskell do you use?

Comment: It didn't compile because you left out the `b` in the recursive call to `log'`, that's all.

Comment: @romeovs, it is simple, but (now you understand how) the interaction between floating and integral types can sometimes be a headache.  Tread carefully.

Answer (score 3):

You need to insert a `fromIntegral` in your definition of `log'` to take care of the return type of `floor`:

```
log' b 0 = 0
log' b k = 1 + log' b (fromIntegral $ floor $ logBase b k)
```

`log'` will then expect both its arguments to be a `Floating` type.